# Decorators not applied to implementation types specified in RegisterAll

Tags: .net, simple-injector

In this code:

```
container.Register<IDataHoldingSession<DbContext>, EntityFrameworkSession>();
container.RegisterAll<ISession>(typeof(IDataHoldingSession<DbContext>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IDataHoldingSession<>), typeof(ValidatingSession<>));
```

When the container is asked for `IEnumerable<ISession>`, it is given a collection containing `EntityFrameworkSession`, but the decorator is not applied. How can I make it apply the decorator in the above code?

I believe this occurs because the container is not asked for `IEnumerable<IDataHoldingSession<T>>`. I interpret the XML documentation for `RegisterAll` as implying that the container will be asked for an instance of `IDataHoldingSession<DbContext>` in this case, which I figure should cause the decorator to be applied. However, it appears that the decorator is bypassed for this situation because `RegisterAll` is called with the `ISession` service type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A registration in Simple Injector contains of two parts:

1. An `InstanceProducer`. This is the object produces instances and is responsible for interception and decorating instances. The `InstanceProducer` doesn't know the `TImplementation` of a registration, only the `TService`.
2. The `InstanceProducer` wraps an `Registration` object. This object is responsible for building an Expression that creates the instance, does constructor injection, property injection, custom initialization, and it applies the lifestyle to the expression. The `Registration` (only) knows about the `TImplementation`.

When you make a `RegisterAll` registration, you supply types that reference other registrations that are made in the container. You are doing this by doing both `Register<IDataHoldingSession<DbContext>>` and using that interface type in your `RegisterAll` registration.

What `RegisterAll` does under the covers, is querying the container for a registration of the given type (in your case `IDataHoldingSession<DbContext>`). Since the requested type might be different from the service type of the collection (it usually does, and does in your case) the container grabs the `Registration` from the found `InstanceProducer` and it creates a new `InstanceProducer` based on that `Registration` with the actual service type of the collection. This looks as follows in the Simple Injector source code (in `ContainerControlledCollection`):

```
return new InstanceProducer(typeof(TService), instanceProducer.Registration);
```

But since decorators are applied by the `InstanceProducer`, we lose the decorator that you applied to `IDataHoldingSession<T>`.

To be frank, I'm not sure why we implemented the behavior like this, since the most intuitive behavior would let the decorator for `IDataHoldingSession<T>` still be applied. I think we tried to prevent having decorators being applied twice; this was a problem in earlier releases of Simple Injector.

I'll try to look into this and look if I can come up with a fix for v2.4, but I can only do this if I don't introduce a breaking change. In the meantime, I think the workaround you found yourself it very good. If I make the fix, I'll probably implement it internally much like you are doing now.

I'm sorry that Simple Injector isn't working the way you expected it to be.

**UPDATE:**

I just checked in a bug fix in the main branch that fixes [this issue](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/20367). The [v2.4 release](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/releases/view/109300) contains this fix.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by supplying `Registration`s to `RegisterAll`. I set the service type of each registration to its specific service type rather than `ISession`.

Here's an extension method that demonstrates this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Same as <see cref="Container.RegisterAll"/>, except each implementation service
/// is individually resolved from the container for compatibility with decorators.
/// </summary>
public static void RegisterAllBugFixed<TService>(this Container container, 
    params Type[] serviceTypes)
{
    var registrations = 
        from serviceType in serviceTypes
        select Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(
            serviceType,
            () => container.GetInstance(serviceType), 
            container);

    container.RegisterAll(typeof(TService), registrations);
}
```